# When brewing from extract recipes should one assume dry or liquid extract if unspecified?

Tags: extract, extract-brewing

When brewing from extract recipes (*e.g.* [Day After 1040A Wheat](http://beerrecipes.org/showrecipe.php?recipeid=185)) should one assume dry malt extract (DME) or liquid malt extract (LME) if unspecified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to know is to look at the OG.  LME has 36 ppg and DME has about 45.  In the recipe you mention, the OG is 1.038 for 5 gal. and it calls for 6 lb. of extract.  Assuming LME, 36*6=216.  Divide by 5 for 5 gal. and you get 43ish.  That's darn close to the OG listed and DME would make the OG even higher, so that particular recipe must be for LME.  There's really no other way to tell.